# How to tail -F, but keep it only scrolling output in last 5 lines

Tags: bash, tail

I'd like to be able to `tail -F` some output, but not have it scrollback the entire buffer, only scroll inside a limited number of lines, say 5 lines.

How can I do this?

I tried

`tail -F -n 5 /tmp/dump`

but that doesn't seem to work - scrolling lines take up the whole buffer

Comment: may be try this `watch -n 0.5 tail -n 5 /tmp/dump`  this executes the tail command every 0.5 seconds

Comment: good point - but `watch` clears the entire screen - i dont want it to clear the entire screen, but do it "in place", and have it replace the last 5 lines in the buffer - I know this can be done for a single line, as seen by commands like so: `seq 1 1000000 | while read i; do echo -en "\r$i"; done`, but I haven't seen it done with multiple lines

Comment: `tail` just writes to standard output; it's your terminal that displays standard output as a scrolling buffer. The behavior you want would have to be implemented by a special version of `tail` or by your terminal; standard `tail` is insufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution isn't pretty - it uses an ANSI escape sequence - but I think it does roughly what you want without using `watch`:

```
while true; do
    tail -5 /tmp/dump | cut -c1-80
    printf '\e[5A'
    sleep 1
done
```

The sequence `\e[5A` means go up five lines. The `5` can be replaced with whatever number you'd like.

That said, you'd be better off using a curses-like library for this kind of thing. Using raw ANSI escape sequences isn't portable. `tput` is avaiable in Linux and Cygwin. The `cuu` capability moves up lines.

```
while true; do
    tail -5 /tmp/dump | cut -c1-80
    tput cuu 5
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: hmmmm... interesting... this is definitely along the lines of what i was thinking! I'll play with it... thanks!

Comment: @BradParks It turns out `tput` is a thing. I've updated my answer.

Comment: nice! I'll try it out some more, but initial tests seem promising... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`tail -5f /tmp/dump`
Weirdly this is different across distros. For some reason the `--retry` doesn't work with it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm on osx, and tried it with osx tail and with gnu tail, and it didn't work for either... I wonder if I could `brew install` a tail like the one you're using?

Comment: This is necessarily implementation- or terminal-dependent. Normally, `tail` simply writes to standard output. `tail` would either have to take control of the terminal more directly, or the terminal itself would have to provide a "region" to which `tail`'s output is limited.

Comment: The idea that commands like this seem to overwrite the previous line of output - or the current line, i guess, that makes this seem possible, though I get what you're saying - maybe it's not....

```seq 1 1000000 | while read i; do echo -en "\r$i"; done```

Comment: You can always mess with escape sequences - `printf "\e{A"` will return to the line before. Again terminal dependent